# PHP dynamic variable returning NULL after upgrading from PHP 5 to PHP 7

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to fix an old website of mine which does currently not work. I have cut down the problem to the following code:

```
<?php

global $options;


foreach ( $options as $value ) {
if ( isset( $value['id'] ) ) {

    var_dump($value);  

    $test = $value['id'];

    if ( get_option( $value['id'] ) === FALSE ) {
        $$value['id'] = $value['std'];
    } else {
        $$value['id'] = get_option( $value['id'] );
    }

    var_dump($$value['id']);  // returns "Boxed"
    var_dump($$test);  // return NULL
    break;
}
}

?>
```

The var_dump of the $value variable is:

```
array(6) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Theme Type" ["desc"]=> string(29) "Select the type of the theme." ["id"]=> string(10) "celta_type" ["type"]=> string(6) "select" ["options"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Boxed" [1]=> string(9) "Stretched" } ["std"]=> string(5) "Boxed" } string(5) "Boxed" NULL array(6) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Theme Type" ["desc"]=> string(29) "Select the type of the theme." ["id"]=> string(10) "celta_type" ["type"]=> string(6) "select" ["options"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Boxed" [1]=> string(9) "Stretched" }
```

What i do not understand is the following: how is it possible that the output $$value['id'] works, but assigning the value to $test = $value['id'] first, results in $$test not working.

The old website was on a very old PHP version (<5.3), did something change in the newer PHP revisions maybe?

thanks for a point in the right direction

Comment: Syntax error $test != $$test

Comment: can you explain this a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `$$value['id']` with `${$value['id']}`.

This is because:

- If $value is a string, like "cheese", then the dynamic variable would resolve to `$cheese['id']`, i.e. you would be looking for an array called `$cheese` with a key of `id`
- If $value is an array, like `['id' => 'celta_type']`, as in your case, then the dynamic variable would resolve to `$celta_type`

This is called an ambiguity problem, see here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

You are right that this changed between PHP 5 and PHP 7: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect

---

By the way, if I were you I wouldn't use dynamic variables as they are unsafe and unpredictable. You could rewrite your function to use an array as follows:

```
$optionValues[$value['id']] = get_option($value['id']);

if ($optionValues[$value['id']] === false)
    $optionValues[$value['id']] = $value['std'];
```

Or

```
$optionValues[$value['id']] = get_option($value['id']) === false ? $value['std'] : get_option($value['id']);
```

Comment: thank you for that detailed answer. that makes a lot of sense